# PHP search a 2 dimensional array then display the entire array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a question. I have some arrays, like in the example below.

```
$arrays = array(

  array('id' => '1','username' => 'user1','password' => 'pass1','email' => 'your@email.com'),

  array('id' => '2','username' => 'user2','password' => 'pass2','email' => 'your@email.com'),

  array('id' => '3','username' => 'user3','password' => 'pass3','email' => 'your@email.com')
);
```

For example, I want to search for "user2" and then display all the information about user2. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know the functions. I need just the names of the functions because I can't find anything in google :(

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the top array (`$arrays`) looking for the correct user. When you have found it do something with it.

```
foreach ($arrays as $a) {
    if (isset($a['username']) && $a['username'] === 'user2') {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($a); 
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to echo the information of the specific username=user2 you can use like the answer before print_r or use :`

```
foreach ($arrays as $a) {
    if ($a['username'] === 'user2') {

echo 'id:'.$a['id'];
 echo 'user:'.$a['username'];
 echo 'email:'.$a['email'];

    }
}
```

and format as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also to search `multidimensional` array by key value

```
$array = array(

    array('id' => '1','username' => 'user1','password' => 'pass1','email' => 'your@email.com'),

    array('id' => '2','username' => 'user2','password' => 'pass2','email' => 'your@email.com'),

    array('id' => '3','username' => 'user3','password' => 'pass3','email' => 'your@email.com')
);

function search_by_key_value($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search_by_key_value($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

$result=search_by_key_value($array,'username','user2'); //array,key,value

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```